# How do I create groups of accessories that I can assign to simple products? Magento Community

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2

On our site, we have many products that will use the same "set" of accessories to display as upsell items on front end, so I am looking for a convenient way to assign accessories to the products without having to do them one by one for each and every product. We upload 100's of new products daily and would prefer to create accessory "groups" that we can assign. My current developers say this is not possible in Magento but I have a hard time believing that. I am not a developer myself, so I am reaching out to the community to try and find a solution I can pass along to my team, or possibly understand myself. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Magento is a very capable, fully fledged MVC framework in it's own right so really anything is possible - consider getting yourself a new developer.

Answer (score 0):

Simply extend Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List_Upsell and add in your extra products using whatever algorithm you need. You can set it so that the products returned is always your preferred number.

You can also apply logic to make sure that you are not repeating products (upsell of current product not good).

With the site I am currently working on we pull through products from the same category, and, if none found, from the parent category, or, failing that, a list of favourites we have stored in a hidden category. You could do the same, putting your accessory bundles in category pages that are not visible from the front end.